# Count and delete duplicates in the same day in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, python-datetime

We see in the attached table that `serial_number` `A` was printed on January 3rd twice, and `serial_number` `C` was printed twice on January 2nd. I wanna delete the duplicated `serial_number` on the same day (yellow marked in the attached picture) as they were there by mistake. Usual Pandas code deletes all duplicates by keeping last or first where I wanna delete them based on the same day presence.

```
from pickle import TRUE
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import datetime
from datetime import date, timedelta
df = pd.read_csv('https://gist.githubusercontent.com/JishanAhmed2019/6f7dd4f54c1c1b2a7fbeaea3aa2a3f43/raw/09f7fd269b8ab977e6dce580fd0c7b7058b42d4c/failure_dub.csv',sep='\t')

df.duplicated(['serial_number']).sum()

df.sort_values('date').drop_duplicates('serial_number',keep='last')
```

[image]

Comment: `df.drop_duplicates(['date', 'serial_number'], keep='last')` (or whatever else you want for `keep`)

Answer (score 0):

You likely need to pass `subset` to `drop_duplicates`:

```
df.drop_duplicates(subset=['date', 'serial_number'], keep='last')
```